# Choose three countries. For each country, find the deadliest date (measured by highest number of new deaths). need help to write logic in Python

Tags: python

Choose three countries. For each country, find the deadliest date (measured by highest number of new deaths). Find the date with the highest new cases. By how many days those two dates are apart from each other? need help to write logic in Python. thx in advance!

Comment: how should we help you give us no information -  do you work with pandas? How is the data-structurer of your country data?  And also give an example of your tries.

Comment: Do you have the data given to you or do you have to collect it from somewhere?
Please provide a minimal example of what you're trying to do to show you've tried something at least. This is not a homeworkoverflow website.